# Using Laravel-Glide with public/uploads folder

Tags: image, laravel-5.3, php-glide

I'd like to use [Glide](http://glide.thephpleague.com/) for all my image sources.

Following to [this instruction](http://glide.thephpleague.com/1.0/config/integrations/laravel/), I can get an image at `http://myweb.dev/img/test.jpg?w=200&filt=sepia`.

[image]

Route:

```
Route::get('/img/{path}', 'ImageController@show')->where('path', '.*');
```

Controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\Filesystem;
use League\Glide\Responses\LaravelResponseFactory;
use League\Glide\ServerFactory;

class ImageController extends Controller
{
    public function show(Filesystem $filesystem, $path)
    {
        $server = ServerFactory::create([
            'response' => new LaravelResponseFactory(app('request')),
            'source' => $filesystem->getDriver(),
            'cache' => $filesystem->getDriver(),
            'cache_path_prefix' => '.cache',
            'base_url' => 'img',
        ]);

        return $server->getImageResponse($path, request()->all());
    }
}
```

Since all my images are /public/uploads directory, I changed it as following.

Route:

```
Route::get('uploads/{path}', 'ImageController@show')->where('path', '.*');
```

Controller

```
public function show(Filesystem $filesystem, $path)
{
    $server = ServerFactory::create([
        'response' => new LaravelResponseFactory(app('request')),
        'source' => public_path(),
        'cache' => public_path(),
        'cache_path_prefix' => '.cache',
        'base_url' => 'uploads',
    ]);

    return $server->getImageResponse($path, request()->all());
}
```

When I go to http://myweb.dev/uploads/test.jpg?w=200&filt=sepia, I get an image without any change nor any .cache directory is created.

I tried `base_path()` and `/uploads` as well, but didn't work either. I am using uploads directory for elfinder.

What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This worked. I put images in `public/uploads` directory.

Route

```
Route::get('/img/{path}', 'ImageController@show')->where('path', '.*');
```

Controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\Filesystem;
use League\Glide\Responses\LaravelResponseFactory;
use League\Glide\ServerFactory;

class ImageController extends Controller
{
    public function show(Filesystem $filesystem, $path)
    {
        $server = ServerFactory::create([
            'response' => new LaravelResponseFactory(app('request')),
            'source' => public_path('uploads'),
            'cache' => public_path('uploads'),
            'cache_path_prefix' => '.cache',
            'base_url' => 'img',
        ]);

        return $server->getImageResponse($path, request()->all());
    }
}
```